# Show that $\tau(R_1 \cap R_2)\subseteq \tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $\tau$ is the transitive closure of a relation $R$ over $A$.

Show that $\tau(R_1 \cap R_2)\subseteq \tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)$

I got up to the point that:

$\tau(R_1 \cap R_2) = (R_1\cap R_2)\cup (R_1\cap R_2)^2\cup ...(R_1\cap R_2)^n ...$

and that:

$\tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)=(R_1\cap R_2)\cup(R_1^2 \cup R_2)... \cup (R_1^n\cap R_2)... $

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a little bit about transitive closure. Let $R$ be a *binary* relation on $A$. The transitive closure $\tau(R)$ of $R$ can be defined in several different ways. First $\tau(R)$ is the smallest transitive set containing $R$. It can be defined as $\tau(R) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} R^n$. One other property that can be used to define transitive closure is $(x, y) \in \tau(R)$ iff $\exists z_0, ..., z_n \in A$ such that $x = z_0$, $y = z_n$ and $(z_i, z_{i+1}) \in R$ for $i = 0, ..., n - 1$. This is easy to derive from $\tau(R) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} R^n$.

Back to the question. Assume $(x, y) \in \tau(R_1 \cap R_2)$. Then there are $x = z_0, z_1, ..., z_n = y \in A$ such that $(z_i, z_{i+1}) \in R_1 \cap R_2$. But then $(z_i, z_{i+1}) \in R_1$ and $(z_i, z_{i+1}) \in R_2$ for $i = 0, ..., n - 1$. Then $(x, y) \in \tau(R_1)$ and $(x, y) \in \tau(R_2)$ and so $(x, y) \in \tau(R_1) \cap \tau(R_2)$.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail, I'm still very new at this.

Comment: I've edited my answer for more clarity.

Comment: You might edit the answer because it's not immediately clear that when you say $(z_i , z_{i+1})\in R_1$ that you're referring to the whole chain of numbers from x to y.

Answer (score 3):

We can simply use the following properties:

- If $S_1$, $S_2$ are transitive, then $S_1\cap S_2$ is transitive.
- For any relation $R$ we have $R\subseteq \tau(R)$
- If $S$ is transitive relation and $R\subseteq S$, then $\tau(R) \subseteq S$.

Now $R_1\subseteq\tau(R_1)$ and $R_2\subseteq\tau(R_2)$, hence $R_1\cap R_2\subseteq \tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)$.

Since both $\tau(R_1)$ and $\tau(R_2)$ are transitive, their intersection $\tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)$ is transitive as well.

We see that $R_1\cap R_2\subseteq\tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)$ and $\tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)$ is transitive. By the third claim I mentioned above we get $\tau(R_1\cap R_2)\subseteq\tau(R_1)\cap\tau(R_2)$ .

---

**Possible generalization:**

Transitive closure is a special case of [closure operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator). Another example of closure operator is closure in topological space.

You can notice that we only used the properties which are true for every closure operator. (If $c: \mathcal P(X) \to \mathcal P(X)$ is a closure operator then the sets fulfilling $c(A)=A$ are closed. In your example, they are the transitive sets. In can be shown that, for aribtrary closure operator, intersection of closed sets is closed.)

Comment: +1 for a nice elegant answer.  I accepted the other answer because I learned more that I didn't understand from it.  Thanks.